# Consuming Simple WCF from Android

Tags: java, android, .net, wcf

I am writing a simple app, that needs to verify login details through a MySQL database. I specifically cannot use PHP, so I opted for the WCF service model. Now, I have the WCF working through my browser. All of the get methods are working in my browser and returns the desired JSON output, but for good order, I will post the Service Interface;

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "getUserAuthenticated/{value1}/{value2}")]
    bool GetUserAuthenticated(string value1, string value2);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "getIsUserModel/{value}")]
    bool GetIsUserModel(string value);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "getIsUserActive/{value}")]
    bool GetIsUserActive(string value);
```

As stated, this works. But when trying to consume the service from my app like so;

```
    public void UserAuthenticated(String email, String password) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.0.180:15021/Service1.svc/GetUserAuthenticated/" + email + "/" + password);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            Log.d("Response Code: ", "" + httpURLConnection.getResponseCode());
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
            String response = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(in, "UTF-8");
            Log.d("Response String: ", response);

        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            mue.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am getting java.io.FileNotFoundException.

```
02-08 04:44:53.015 7425-7457/com.testapp W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.0.0.180:15021/Service1.svc/GetUserAuthenticated/user/pass
02-08 04:44:53.015 7425-7457/com.testapp W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
02-08 04:44:53.015 7425-7457/com.testapp W/System.err:     at com.testapp.LoginClass.UserAuthenticated(LoginClass.java:29)
02-08 04:44:53.015 7425-7457/com.testapp W/System.err:     at com.test.WelcomeScreen$LoginAuthenticator.doInBackground(WelcomeScreen.java:103)
02-08 04:44:53.015 7425-7457/com.testapp W/System.err:     at com.testapp.WelcomeScreen$LoginAuthenticator.doInBackground(WelcomeScreen.java:90)
02-08 04:44:53.015 7425-7457/com.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-08 04:44:53.015 7425-7457/com.testapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-08 04:44:53.015 7425-7457/com.testapp W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-08 04:44:53.019 7425-7457/com.testapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-08 04:44:53.019 7425-7457/com.testapp W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-08 04:44:53.019 7425-7457/com.testapp W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-08 04:44:53.023 7425-7425/com.testapp W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-08 04:44:53.155 577-912/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@529adc88 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@52b37f04
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction here? All the examples I've been able to find use the deprecated HttpClient to handle WCF consumption, and I don't think it's good practice to use drepecated classes to handle this.

I am kinda lost here, so any help will be greatly appriciated!

EDIT:
Googled about a bit and made the HttpURLConnection print what response code it was getting. I am getting a 400 BAD REQUEST from the service.

EDIT2:

I created an Azure site to run my service through, which, for the time being has solved my problem. However, I am still interested in why I cannot connect to the service when running it on local host.

Comment: Did you try changing URL template to this UriTemplate = "getUserAuthenticated/?value1={value1}&value2={value2}"

Comment: Also update URL like this *http://10.0.0.180:15021/Service1.svc/GetUserAuthenticated/?value1=user&value2=pass*

Comment: Just updated to your suggested UriTemplate. Still working fine in browser, but when running from emulator or device, still getting response code 400.
Tried changing the port as well, to 8008. Opened the port in windows firewall, but still unable to get through.

Comment: Are you using `Local IIS` or `IIS Express`?

Comment: Local. But now I've run into a different problem, that I will google before I do anything else.

Comment: Try using `http://computername/...` rather than `localhost` or `ip number`. It works for me.

Comment: @jstreet - That didn't work. However, I got it to work now! I had to port forward the emulator in order to get access.

Comment: Post an answer with exactly what you did so others can learn from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it. What I did was;

1. I opened the port I was attempting to connect on in Windows Firewall. In my case 8008. I opened it both for outgoing and ingoing traffic.
2. I installed IIS Express, and set up a local page on the IP that my workstation has.
3. After a lot of rumaging about on the interwebz, and here on Stack Overflow, I found other who had problems connecting to local IIS addresses through Genymotion, even using the standard IP for localhost, 10.0.3.2. From another thread here on SO I found this guide;

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Turns out, I had to port forward the device. And now it is working. I can now connect to my WCF service through my Genymotion emulator on my workstations IP at port 8008.

I hope this helps someone.

Cheers.